# Columns and rows flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, I am having an issue where I can mostly get my flexbox working, except when it comes to two columns side by side with uneven rows beside each other. For the life of me I can't figure out why it isn't working.

Here is the screenshot of how it looks now:
http://prntscr.com/ndig4v (by lightshot)
[image]

Here is the HTML:

```css
/* Stats */
#stats-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
#free-stats {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
#stats-column-one,
#stats-column-two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#stats-column-one {
  width: 75%;
}
#stats-column-two {
  width: 25%;
}
#stats-flex-one,
#stats-flex-two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#str-row,
#end-row,
#dex-row,
#eva-row,
#int-row,
#res-row,
#has-row {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  border: 1px yellow solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="stats-container" class="yellow-black-shadow">
  <div id="free-stats">FS</div>
  <div id="stats-column-one">
    <div id="stats-flex-one">
      <div id="str-row">
        <div class="stat-icon"></div>
        <div id="str">SR</div>
      </div>
      <div id="dex-row">
        <div class="stat-icon"></div>
        <div id="dex">DR</div>
      </div>
      <div id="int-row">
        <div class="stat-icon"></div>
        <div id="int">IR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="stats-flex-two">
      <div id="end-row">
        <div class="stat-icon"></div>
        <div id="str">ER</div>
      </div>
      <div id="eva-row">
        <div class="stat-icon"></div>
        <div id="eva">VR</div>
      </div>
      <div id="res-row">
        <div class="stat-icon"></div>
        <div id="res">RR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="stats-column-two">
    <div id="has-row">
      <div class="stats-icon"></div>
      <div id="has">HR</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically everything is correct, until it reaches the HR block, it SHOULD be on the right side. I want avoid using `float: right;`

I'm pretty sure I am doing this in the wrong order, but I am not sure which order I am messing up. I've played with it some, but each different thing I try I seem to break a bit more, this is the closest I've gotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, I forgot the order in which things are supposed to work, but here is the fix

HTML:

```
<div id="stats-container" class="yellow-black-shadow">
  <div id="free-stats">FS</div>
  <div id="stats-column-container">
    <div id="stats-column-one">
      <div id="stats-flex-one">
        <div id="str-row">
          <div class="stat-icon"></div>
          <div id="str">SR</div>
        </div>
        <div id="dex-row">
          <div class="stat-icon"></div>
          <div id="dex">DR</div>
        </div>
        <div id="int-row">
          <div class="stat-icon"></div>
          <div id="int">IR</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="stats-flex-two">
        <div id="end-row">
          <div class="stat-icon"></div>
          <div id="str">ER</div>
        </div>
        <div id="eva-row">
          <div class="stat-icon"></div>
          <div id="eva">VR</div>
        </div>
        <div id="res-row">
          <div class="stat-icon"></div>
          <div id="res">RR</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="stats-column-two">
      <div id="has-row">
        <div class="stats-icon"></div>
        <div id="has">HR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just wrapped it all in another contain div, and added:

```
#stats-column-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

I also removed this completely

```
#stats-column-one,
#stats-column-two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

For reference on how it was supposed to look
http://prntscr.com/ndijk0 (by lightshot)

Hope this may help someone understand the order better in the future cause it confuses me sometimes.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer to get your "Self Learner" badge :)

Comment: I will but it takes 2 days to do so :(